# Flutter google_sign_in Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)

Tags: flutter, firebase, error-handling, google-signin

I currently have an error every time I try to connect to my app with google_sign_in :

[goole_sign_in error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzG3t.png)

/!\  Note that I already changed the sha keys in my firebase project and downloaded the google services file. Also it worked well not long ago and stopped working suddenly.

Here is my code for the google sign in :

```
Future<UserCredential?> signInWithGoogle()async{
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount? gUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication gAuth = await gUser!.authentication;
      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: gAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: gAuth.idToken,
      );
      return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
      return null;
    }
    
  }
```